# mpu-6050 sparkfun breakout board

Tags: breakout

How do I change the LSB of the I2C address of the Sparkfun's MPU-6050 breakout board? From the schematics on the Sparkfun's web page ( https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11028 ) this pin (A0) is soldered to the ground, so the address is xxxx0, but there is a "solder jump" between the chip's A0 and this soldering. I would like to change the adress from xxxx0 to xxxx1 (connect A0 to VDD). I am supposed to connect this "solder jump" to VCC directly, or am I supposed to unsolder A0-GND first to prevent short-circuits to happen? I don't usually do electronics, so I don't want to blow up everything by trying to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disconnect it from GND and connect it to Vcc. Look at the second photo on sparkfun, as you can see there's that nice solder blob on the *right* side of AD0: you need to get rid of it, then you'll reveal three little pads: the center is connected to the chip, on the right you have ground while on the left you have Vcc. Now you only have to solder center with left and you are good to go. Just be careful not to short ground and Vcc: your power source might not be protected from short circuits and you risk to either destroy the PSU or burn the solder blob (very, **very** unlikely).

It just requires a bit of dexterity, really.

Comment: So what is the solder jump for, which they advertise about in the features list (third in the list)? Also fun thing, my breakout board has an additional hole on the left of "FSYNC", under the solder blob, connected to the chip's A0.

Comment: Solder jump = solder blob, that's what it's for. The boards might differ a bit from version to version, but the solder jump is probably the same.

Comment: @Vulpo Hi! This is important: FSYNC should be connected to ground, not A0.  Of course, when A0 is also connected to ground, then it will be connected to FSYNC, too.  But when you change A0 from GND to Vcc, FSYNC and A0 should no longer be connected.